# Sequelize JOIN with function in conditoin

Tags: join, sequelize.js

I googled a bit, looked into documentation but no sign for functions in join conditions

I wanna do (pls ignore the obvious issue with the db design => name_department instead of id_department.. this is just an example)

```
SELECT *
FROM emp e
JOIN department d
ON e.name_department = lower(d.name_department)
```

How do I define such relation in the Sequelize model ???

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const { db } = require('./../../db/sequelize')
const dbConfig = require('./../../config/db.config')

const Department = require('./department.model')

const Employee = db.define('emp', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255)
  },
  name_department: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255)
  }
}, {
  schema: dbConfig.backendSchema,
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
})

Employee.hasOne(Department, {as: 'dpt', foreignKey: 'name_department', sourceKey: '????????'})

module.exports = Employee
```

How do I implement the function there? I simply tried -> `lower(name_department)` but it doesn't work ... is there any way to use functions?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with Sequelize to indicate something other than a real field from a table/view.

One possible solution is to add a field with calculated function result and join two models using this field (Obviously it would be totally up to you to keep this field up-to-date).